# How to run simple Spark app from Eclipse/Intellij IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

To ease the development of my map reduce tasks running on Hadoop prior to actually deploying the tasks to Hadoop I test using a simple map reducer I wrote :

```
object mapreduce {
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  val intermediate = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.List[Int]]
                                                  //> intermediate  : java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.List[Int]] = {}
  val result = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]       //> result  : java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []

  def emitIntermediate(key: String, value: Int) {
    if (!intermediate.containsKey(key)) {
      intermediate.put(key, new java.util.ArrayList)
    }
    intermediate.get(key).add(value)
  }                                               //> emitIntermediate: (key: String, value: Int)Unit

  def emit(value: Int) {
    println("value is " + value)
    result.add(value)
  }                                               //> emit: (value: Int)Unit

  def execute(data: java.util.List[String], mapper: String => Unit, reducer: (String, java.util.List[Int]) => Unit) {

    for (line <- data) {
      mapper(line)
    }

    for (keyVal <- intermediate) {
      reducer(keyVal._1, intermediate.get(keyVal._1))
    }

    for (item <- result) {
      println(item)
    }
  }                                               //> execute: (data: java.util.List[String], mapper: String => Unit, reducer: (St
                                                  //| ring, java.util.List[Int]) => Unit)Unit

  def mapper(record: String) {
    var jsonAttributes = com.nebhale.jsonpath.JsonPath.read("$", record, classOf[java.util.ArrayList[String]])
    println("jsonAttributes are " + jsonAttributes)
    var key = jsonAttributes.get(0)
    var value = jsonAttributes.get(1)

    println("key is " + key)
    var delims = "[ ]+";
    var words = value.split(delims);
    for (w <- words) {
      emitIntermediate(w, 1)
    }
  }                                               //> mapper: (record: String)Unit

  def reducer(key: String, listOfValues: java.util.List[Int]) = {
    var total = 0
    for (value <- listOfValues) {
      total += value;
    }

    emit(total)
  }                                               //> reducer: (key: String, listOfValues: java.util.List[Int])Unit
  var dataToProcess = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
                                                  //> dataToProcess  : java.util.ArrayList[String] = []
  dataToProcess.add("[\"test1\" , \"test1 here is another test1 test1 \"]")
                                                  //> res0: Boolean = true
  dataToProcess.add("[\"test2\" , \"test2 here is another test2 test1 \"]")
                                                  //> res1: Boolean = true

  execute(dataToProcess, mapper, reducer)         //> jsonAttributes are [test1, test1 here is another test1 test1 ]
                                                  //| key is test1
                                                  //| jsonAttributes are [test2, test2 here is another test2 test1 ]
                                                  //| key is test2
                                                  //| value is 2
                                                  //| value is 2
                                                  //| value is 4
                                                  //| value is 2
                                                  //| value is 2
                                                  //| 2
                                                  //| 2
                                                  //| 4
                                                  //| 2
                                                  //| 2


  for (keyValue <- intermediate) {
      println(keyValue._1 + "->"+keyValue._2.size)//> another->2
                                                  //| is->2
                                                  //| test1->4
                                                  //| here->2
                                                  //| test2->2
   }


}
```

This allows me to run my mapreduce tasks within my Eclipse IDE on Windows before deploying to the actual Hadoop cluster. I would like to perform something similar for Spark or have the ability to write Spark code from within Eclipse to test prior to deploying to Spark cluster. Is this possible with Spark ? Since Spark runs on top of Hadoop does this mean I cannot run Spark without first having Hadoop installed ? So in other words can I run the code using just the Spark libraries ? :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "$YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple App", "YOUR_SPARK_HOME",
      List("target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar"))
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

taken from https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/quick-start.html#a-standalone-app-in-scala

If so what are the Spark libraries I need to include within my project ?

Comment: [spark.apache.org](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) indicates spark-core_2.10, version 0.9.0-incubating.   I'd start with that an it's dependencies. You can find that [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/0.9.0-incubating) or [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse|-183575761).  If you're not creating your project with a dependency management plugin to create your eclipse project, you'll have to download the dependencies yourself.  One does appear to be hadoop-client.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your build.sbt
`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.9.1"` and make sure your `scalaVersion` is set (eg. `scalaVersion := "2.10.3"`)

Also if you're just running the program locally, you can skip the last two arguments to SparkContext as follows `val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple App")`

Finally, Spark can run on Hadoop but can also run in stand alone mode. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/spark-standalone.html

Comment: You'd also need to regenerate the Eclipse project using sbteclipse and possibly refresh the project inside Eclipse.

Comment: Does this work directly? Don't you need to package a jar and submit it to spark-submit?